# How do I debug a program which I set to start at login, but it doesn't?

Tags: login, startup-applications

I have a program I want to run when I login. I added it using the "Startup Applications" program, as I have done before to run other things.

But this program doesn't start automatically.

If I run it manually after logging in, it works fine.

So.. how do I debug this?

The program in question is gtk-redshift, FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `~/.xsession-errors` - if the app produces some error messages, they will appear in this file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But while I see tons of warning messages from other programs (mostly Nautilus), I don't see anything about gtk-redshift.

Comment: @Jeremy in this case, the failure might occur in redshift, so it won;t be easy to debug this. Please contact [redshift developer](https://launchpad.net/~jonls/+contactuser) on detailed procedure.